# Need to Test a Service that Uses CURL in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-5.1

I built a service in for my Laravel 5.1 API that searches YouTube. I am trying to write a test for it but am having trouble figuring out how to mock the functionality. Below is the service.

```
class Youtube
{
/**
 * Youtube API Key
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $apiKey;

/**
 * Youtube constructor.
 *
 * @param $apiKey
 */
public function __construct($apiKey)
{
    $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
}

/**
 * Perform YouTube video search.
 *
 * @param $channel
 * @param $query
 * @return mixed
 */
public function searchYoutube($channel, $query)
{
    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date' .
        '&part=snippet' .
        '&channelId=' . urlencode($channel) .
        '&type=video' .
        '&maxResults=25' .
        '&key=' . urlencode($this->apiKey) .
        '&q=' . urlencode($query);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $result = json_decode($result, true);

    if ( is_array($result) && count($result) ) {
        return $this->extractVideo($result);
    }
    return $result;
}

/**
 * Extract the information we want from the YouTube search resutls.
 * @param $params
 * @return array
 */
protected function extractVideo($params)
{
    /*
    // If successful, YouTube search returns a response body with the following structure:
    //
    //{
    //  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
    //  "etag": etag,
    //  "nextPageToken": string,
    //  "prevPageToken": string,
    //  "pageInfo": {
    //    "totalResults": integer,
    //    "resultsPerPage": integer
    //  },
    //  "items": [
    //    {
    //        "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
    //        "etag": etag,
    //        "id": {
    //            "kind": string,
    //            "videoId": string,
    //            "channelId": string,
    //            "playlistId": string
    //        },
    //        "snippet": {
    //            "publishedAt": datetime,
    //            "channelId": string,
    //            "title": string,
    //            "description": string,
    //            "thumbnails": {
    //                (key): {
    //                    "url": string,
    //                    "width": unsigned integer,
    //                    "height": unsigned integer
    //                }
    //            },
    //        "channelTitle": string,
    //        "liveBroadcastContent": string
    //      }
    //  ]
    //}
     */
    $results = [];
    $items = $params['items'];

    foreach ($items as $item) {

        $videoId = $items['id']['videoId'];
        $title = $items['snippet']['title'];
        $description = $items['snippet']['description'];
        $thumbnail = $items['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url'];

        $results[] = [
            'videoId' => $videoId,
            'title' => $title,
            'description' => $description,
            'thumbnail' => $thumbnail
        ];
    }

    // Return result from YouTube API
    return ['items' => $results];
}
}
```

I created this service to abstract the functionality from a controller. I then used Mockery to test the controller. Now I need to figure out how to test the service above. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to say, your class is not designed for isolated unit testing because of hardcoded `curl_*` methods. For make it better you have at least 2 options:

1) Extract `curl_*` functions calls to another class and pass that class as a parameter

```
class CurlCaller {

    public function call($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }

}

class Youtube
{
    public function __construct($apiKey, CurlCaller $caller)
    {
        $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
        $this->caller = $caller;
    }
}
```

Now you can easily mock CurlCaller class.
There is a lot of ready solutions that abstracts network. For example, [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) is great

2) Another option is to extract `curl_*` calls to protected method and mock that method. Here is a working example:

```
// Firstly change your class:
class Youtube
{
    // ...

    public function searchYoutube($channel, $query)
    {
        $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date' .
            '&part=snippet' .
            '&channelId=' . urlencode($channel) .
            '&type=video' .
            '&maxResults=25' .
            '&key=' . urlencode($this->apiKey) .
            '&q=' . urlencode($query);
        $result = $this->callUrl($url);

        $result = json_decode($result, true);

        if ( is_array($result) && count($result) ) {
            return $this->extractVideo($result);
        }
        return $result;
    }

    // This method will be overriden in test.
    protected function callUrl($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Now you can mock method `callUrl`. But first, lets put expected api response to `fixtures/youtube-response-stub.json` file.

```
class YoutubeTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testYoutube()
    {
        $apiKey = 'StubApiKey';

        // Here we create instance of Youtube class and tell phpunit that we want to override method 'callUrl'
        $youtube = $this->getMockBuilder(Youtube::class)
            ->setMethods(['callUrl'])
            ->setConstructorArgs([$apiKey])
            ->getMock();

        // This is what we expect from youtube api but get from file
        $fakeResponse = $this->getResponseStub();

        // Here we tell phpunit how to override method and our expectations about calling it
        $youtube->expects($this->once())
            ->method('callUrl')
            ->willReturn($fakeResponse);

        // Get results
        $list = $youtube->searchYoutube('UCSZ3kvee8aHyGkMtShH6lmw', 'php');

        $expected = ['items' => [[
            'videoId' => 'video-id-stub',
            'title' => 'title-stub',
            'description' => 'description-stub',
            'thumbnail' => 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/stub/thimbnail-stub.jpg',
        ]]];

        // Finally assert result with what we expect
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $list);
    }

    public function getResponseStub()
    {
        $response = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/fixtures/youtube-response-stub.json');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Run test and... OMG FAILURE!!1 You have typos in `extractVideo` method, should be `$item` instead of `$items`. Lets fix it

```
$videoId = $item['id']['videoId'];
$title = $item['snippet']['title'];
$description = $item['snippet']['description'];
$thumbnail = $item['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url'];
```

OK, now it pass.

---

If you want to test your class with call to Youtube API you just need to create normal Youtube class.

---

BTW, there is [php-youtube-api](https://github.com/madcoda/php-youtube-api) lib, which has providers for laravel 4 and laravel 5, also it has tests

Answer (score 0):

If changing the code where the CURL calls are made isn't an option, it can still be done, but it's not pretty.

This solution assumes that the code making the CURL call is basing its target URL on an environment variable.  The gist here is that you can redirect the call back to your own app, to an endpoint where the output can be controlled by your test.  Since the instance of the app where the test is being executed is actually different from that which get accessed when the CURL call makes a U-turn, the way we deal with scoping issues to allow the test to control the output is through `forever` cache, that records your dummy-data to an external file that gets accessed at runtime.

1. Within the test, alter the value of the environment variable responsible for the domain of the CURL call using:
   `putenv("SOME_BASE_URI=".config('app.url')."/curltest/")`

Since `phpunit.xml` typically sets the default `CACHE_DRIVER` to `array`, which is *not* permanent, you'll have to put this in your test to change it back to `file`.

```
config(['cache.default' => 'file']);
```

2. Create a new class within your `tests` folder that will be responsible for returning a given response when the request meets a configurable set of criteria:

   use Illuminate\Http\Request;

   class ResponseFactory {

   ```
   public function getResponse(Request $request)
   {
       $request = [
           'method' => $request->method(),
           'url' => parse_url($request->fullUrl()),
           'parameters' => $request->route()->parameters(),
           'input' => $request->all(),
           'files' => $request->files
       ];

       $responses = app('cache')->pull('test-response', null);

       $response = collect($responses)->filter(function (array $response) use ($request) {
           $passes = true;
           $response = array_dot($response);
           $request = array_dot($request);
           foreach ($response as $part => $rule) {
               if ($part == 'response') {
                   continue;
               }
               $passes &= is_callable($rule) ? $rule($request[$part]) : ($request[$part] == $rule);
           }
           return $passes;
       })->pluck('response')->first() ?: $request;

       if (is_callable($response)) {
           $response = $response($request);
       }

       return response($response);
   }

   /**
    * This uses permanent cache so it can persist between the instance of this app from which the test is being
    * executed, to the instance being accessed by a CURL call
    *
    * @param array $responses
    */
   public function setResponse(array $responses)
   {
       app('cache')->forever('test-response', $responses);
   }
   ```

   }

Since this is in the `tests` folder and not under the `App` namespace, be sure to add it to the `auto-load.classmap` portion of your `composer.json` file, and run `composer dumpautoload;composer install` on the command line.
Also, this is using a custom helper function:

```
if (!function_exists('parse_url')) {
    /**
     * @param $url
     * @return array
     */
    function parse_url($url)
    {
        $parts = parse_url($url);
        if (array_key_exists('query', $parts)) {
            $query = [];
            parse_str(urldecode($parts['query']), $query);
            $parts['query'] = $query;
        }
        return $parts;
    }
}
```

3. Add some testing-only endpoints to your routes.  (Sadly, placing 
   `$this->app->make(Router::class)->match($method, $endpoint, $closure);`
   within your test will not work, so far as I can tell.)

   `Route::post('curltest/{endpoint?}', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
       return app(ResponseFactory::class)->getResponse($request);
   });
   Route::get('curltest/{endpoint?}', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
       return app(ResponseFactory::class)->getResponse($request);
   });
   Route::put('curltest/{endpoint?}', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
       return app(ResponseFactory::class)->getResponse($request);
   });
   Route::patch('curltest/{endpoint?}', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
       return app(ResponseFactory::class)->getResponse($request);
   });
   Route::delete('curltest/{endpoint?}', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
       return app(ResponseFactory::class)->getResponse($request);
   });`

   You can even wrap this in an `if` block if you want, that makes sure `config('app.debug') == true` first.
4. Configure the content of the responses to reflect the endpoint that's suppose to prompt a specific `response` value.  Place something like this inside your test.

   `app(ResponseFactory::class)->setResponse([[
       'url.path' => "/curltest/$curlTargetEndpont",
       'response' => 'success'
   ]]);`